# Highlighting pips/scale on nouislider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nouislider

I am building six sliders using the nouislider library.

I added pips to the sliders. I would like to highlight the value of the pip to the relevant slider is on and update accordingly on slider move.

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxLjx13u/) of what I currently did.

HTML:

```
<div class="sliders" id="slider1"></div>
<br/>
<div class="sliders" id="slider2"></div>
<br/>
<div class="sliders" id="slider3"></div>
<br/>
<div class="sliders" id="slider4"></div>
<br/>
<div class="sliders" id="slider5"></div>
<br/>
<div class="sliders" id="slider6"></div>
```

JS:

```
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('sliders');

for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {

    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
        start: 0,
        step: 1,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 5
        },
        pips: {
            mode: 'values',
            values: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            density: 100
        }
    });
}
```

Any help on how to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `noUiSlider`, but here was something I've put together from their update event in the [documentation](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/). You could use change, but I like the initial highlighting. Keep in mind that this method only works because your values are equivalent to the shown indexes of the elements. Had you started with 1 or any other value, you would need to find a different method to target the `.noUi-value`.

```js
/* Loop Through Sliders */
$('.sliders').each(function() {
    /* Variable Defaults */
    var slider = this;
    
    /* Init noUiSlider */
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: 0,
        step: 1,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 5
        },
        pips: {
            mode: 'values',
            values: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            density: 100
        }
    });

    /* Bind Update Event to noUiSlider */
    slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values) {
        /* Set Maximum Position */
        var maxPos = Math.max(values);
        
        /* Add Highlight Class to Pip */
        $(slider).find('.noUi-value:visible').removeClass('highlight').eq(maxPos).addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

```css
.sliders {
 margin-top: 40px;
}

.noUi-pips-horizontal:last-child .noUi-marker-large, .noUi-marker-sub {
 display: none;
}

.noUi-pips-horizontal {
 top: -55px !important;
}

/* Highlight CSS */
.noUi-value.highlight {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sliders" id="slider1"></div>
<br>
<div class="sliders" id="slider2"></div>
<br>
<div class="sliders" id="slider3"></div>
<br>
<div class="sliders" id="slider4"></div>
<br>
<div class="sliders" id="slider5"></div>
<br>
<div class="sliders" id="slider6"></div>
```